# How Change calling function of onChange event using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have this code which can display drop down in div tag of html. In this I have set one function "hello()" to that drop down through jquery but the problem is that its not calling that function.

```
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#content").append('<select id="sel" onchange="fly()"><option value="1">Choose Me</option></select>');
    $("#sel").attr("onchange", "hello()");
    alert($("#sel").attr("onchange"));

    function hello() {
        alert("Hello");
    }

    function fly() {
        alert("Go to fly");
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this.

```
$("#sel").change(hello);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#sel").attr("onchange", hello);
```

EDIT :

In case you missed it in all the near-identical answers, your original problem was that you put your function in quotes `"hello()"` rather than just using the function name to call it (ie `hello`)...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap it in a jquery initialization

```
$(function(){
    $("#content").append('<select id="sel" onchange="fly()"><option value="1">Choose Me</option></select>');
    $("#sel").attr("onchange", "hello()");
    alert($("#sel").attr("onchange"));

    function hello() {
        alert("Hello");
    }

    function fly() {
        alert("Go to fly");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

```
$("#sel").change(function(){
   hello();
});
```

Also wrap it in the jquery init function to ensure its ran after DOM has fully loaded:

```
$(function(){
   $("#content").append('<select id="sel" onchange="fly()"><option value="1">Choose Me</option></select>')
   $("#sel").change(function(){
      hello();
   });
});
```

Comment: This will execute the hello function, passing the return value (undefined) to change().

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you move:

```
$("#content").append('<select id="sel" onchange="fly()"><option value="1">Choose Me</option></select>'); 
$("#sel").attr("onchange", "hello()"); 
alert($("#sel").attr("onchange"));
```

into a document ready function and remove the `"`s around `hello`, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").append('<select id="sel" onchange="fly()"><option value="1">Choose Me</option></select>'); 
    $("#sel").attr("onchange", hello); 
    alert($("#sel").attr("onchange"));
});
```

This will allow the page to load, and then change the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery. There's a shortcut for most things. It should be:

```
var hello = function() {
   alert("Hello");
}
$("#sel").change(hello);
```

or

```
$("#sel").change(function() {
 alert("Hello");
});
```

It should also be in the document ready function. This is so it doesn't try and attach the event before the elements exist.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but as the others said. the problem its that you are using `$("#sel").attr("onchange", "hello()");` instead of `$("#sel").attr("onchange", hello);`

This is because in JavaScript a function is a data type. So you have to work with [high order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)

If you want to understand better this I'd suggest to learn about functional programming.

Besides that, you should use jQuery methods to add event listeners. In this case `$(.'#sel').change(hello);`